# Android toolbar setNavigationIcon not working

Tags: android, android-toolbar

So, I have a BaseActivity in which I have a toolbar and I call setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

In some of my activities that extends BaseActivity, I would like to change the navigation icon (the default arrow) to another drawable. But when I call toolbar.setNavigationIcon(myDrawable) it doesn't work, it still shows the default left pointing arrow icon.

Any idea? 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525229/toolbar-navigation-icon-never-set

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think you can set like this

```
    menuDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, menuDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){...}

    menuDrawerToggle.syncState();

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(yourDrawable));
```

put setNavigationIcon after syncState()

Comment: WTF!?!? I would never have found this, how the heck did you figure this out?  I'd throw you a bunch of rep if I knew how.

Comment: How does this only have (now 7) votes.  Great find!!

Comment: Great answer. Can't belive it

Comment: This is the right answer. Works like a charm! Life saver!

Comment: What logic does this use? I’ve tried `android:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_navigation”` in my `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` design file and it failed. Tried toolbar.setIcon in onCreate after `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` and it failed but this works. Is there anything in the documentation that mentions that navigationIcon must be set after a call to syncState. What is the issue here / what goes on under the hood?

Answer (score 5):

In my case: I don`t use ActionBarDrawerToggle. For me helpful was:
to change order of methods calls.

From:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_chevron_left_white_24dp);
```

To:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_chevron_left_white_24dp);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, setNavigationIcon after syncState as @Hsieh not work! 
My solution is set in onPostCreate method as below.
Override this method in your activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_button);
    }
```

Comment: oh, there're too many cases for this issue. :'( Share your solutions if you find out, bro!