# How do I change the default navigation button for my toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I made my own button design in drawable and assigned it to `app:navigationIcon`. It showed up nicely under the design view but when I ran my app the default menu icon was shown. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Below is my code for the toolbar:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/dash_toolBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu" />
```

Below is my code for `ic_menu` icon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_circle_red"
        />
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_red"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        />

</layer-list>
```

Below is the code for the circle:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#FF5252"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0" />
</vector>
```

Below is the code for the menu:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2L3,16v2zM3,13h18v-2L3,11v2zM3,6v2h18L21,6L3,6z"/>
</vector>
```

[image: Design view on android studio]

[image: On the emulator]

Comment: In what drawable folder did you place your icon `ic_menu`?

Comment: @HB. It's under the res/drawable folder.

Comment: It happens because the navIcon is tinted the colorOnPrimary with a material components theme.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks for the comment. Is it possible for you to elaborate more on that? I don't quite get it.

Comment: See, if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627636/8244632) helps.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar That worked! I was wondering if there was anyway to change the Icon from the xml file

Comment: If it's not working through XML, you can make custom `ToolBar` layout removing the default one, that way your `NavigationIcon` will be an `ImageView` and that will be used to open the drawer.