# Aviary SDK for Image Editing issue with setNavigationIcon of toolbar

Tags: android, sdk, aviary, image-editing

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById((R.id.app_bar));
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).openDrawer();

            }
        });
```

Here is my code segment. After adding Aviary SDK, image set on 'toolbar.setNavigationIcon(...)' not working & no icon is visible there. My drawer is sliding/working smoothly. I want to use this SDK & want the navigation icon too. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById((R.id.app_bar));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).openDrawer();

            }
        });
```

Just changing the order solved my problem.

Refered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999493/5672138

Answer (score 1):

I think you have use `setNavigationIcon()` method after `ActionBarDrawerToggle` like this:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(your_drawable_icon));
```

If your navigation icon is back icon, then you can get it from `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"`. Your `toolbar` structure be like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"/>
```

Comment: Yes, Its also a possible solution. I also found this, but just chaning the oder sequence was much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting navigation icon on the toolbar before setting toolbar to `setSupportActionBar`.

Or you can try setting `setHomeAsUpIndicator` in `supportActionBar`.