# Android Toolbar "Up" Arrow in custom implementation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation, android-toolbar

I am making a very custom Toolbar (don't freak, it's for good, not evil, I promise), and I want to put the "Up" arrow (the arrow that appears when there is a parent Activity set or for other reasons and has the nice ripple touch effect on Lollipop) in a custom location.

Is there a way to get this arrow as a View or asset to use somewhere else in the Toolbar?

I could not even find the image asset for the arrow.  Any ideas?

For an example, I want top be able to do something like:

```
mToolbar.addView(arrowView, 0);
mToolbar.addView(titleView, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26525742/2364348) will help, looks like something that you want, or you want completely custom up button with different position and view?

Comment: I want to be able to control fully the up arrow as if it were a View.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to place arrow icon as custom view in `Toolbar`, alternatively you can set content description to the navigation button and find view reference later. Every `View` or `ViewGroup` supports [finding views with content description](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/bb963f9b8f40beb954a0).

```
public static View getNavigationIcon(Toolbar toolbar){
    //check if contentDescription previously was set
    boolean hadContentDescription = TextUtils.isEmpty(toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription());
    String contentDescription = !hadContentDescription ? toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription() : "navigationIcon";
    toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(contentDescription);
    ArrayList<View> potentialViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    //find the view based on it's content description, set programatically or with android:contentDescription
    toolbar.findViewsWithText(potentialViews,contentDescription, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
    //Nav icon is always instantiated at this point because calling setNavigationContentDescription ensures its existence 
    View navIcon = null;
    if(potentialViews.size() > 0){
        navIcon = potentialViews.get(0); //navigation icon is ImageButton
    }
     //Clear content description if not previously present
    if(hadContentDescription)
        toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(null);
    return navIcon;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is itself a ViewGroup were you can add different views for eg.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" >

     <TextView ..../>
     <ImageView ...../>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Refer your toolbar and its elements from your java code to have control over it as:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
ImageView img = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imgv);
```

Comment: My question is how to set something like the up arrow.  I know how to set Views in the Toolbar.