# Android navigation button including title like Facebook

Tags: android, android-activity, back, android-toolbar, android-navigation

How can I make the back navigation button contain the activity title?

This is my code, and when I click back, it only clicks in the arrow.

I know how to provide back navigation. I would like to know how I can include the title in the button!

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_alarms_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Alarms");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

[image: Facebook screenshot]

Comment: use a toolbar. add a navigation icon and titile. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525229/toolbar-navigation-icon-never-set

Comment: Read edit, I know how to provide title and navigation.

Comment: the title is set to the toolbar.  It should be that way. Toolbar is a view group so you can add a button with a drawable in case you need it

Comment: So I should make a drawable for every activity?

Comment: For facebook i guess its only for the about screen. For the rest its navigation icon and title for toolbar. i am not even sure if its a toolbar used by them

Comment: Nope, every activity has it, and android L on my galaxy S4 does the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75377/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-georgian-benetatos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took a look at the facebook about screen on Nexus 5 lollipop.

I used a uiautomaterview

So it looks like

[image]

Looking at the root layout at the top is a `RelativeLayout`.

Then you have the `LinearLayout` hosting the `ImageView` and `Textview`.

So the click is on the `LinearLayout`. On click of it navigation back.

Your toolbar is a view group you can probably add the relative layout to the toolbar.