# Problems with Home button in the Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I know it's a common question but I tried a lot of solutions of StackOverflow and any solution works.

I want to show the home button in the toolbar but it shows the back button or nothing.

I tried different codes like:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now I have the code:

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and it shows the back button.

Any solution to show the Home button?
Thanks for the help.

I'm sorry if my English is too bad.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525229/toolbar-navigation-icon-never-set

Comment: do you have a DrawerLayout/Toggle ?

Comment: Yes, I have a DrawerLayout

Comment: @ManelMendez ok, can you post the full code related to SupportActionBar, DrawerLayout and toggle ?

Comment: @HugoGresse of course, is this enough?

Comment: @HugoGresse I posted it as an answer

Comment: @ManelMendez :o do not post this as an answer, as it do not solved you're problem in anyway.

Comment: @MarekSebera I have to add an icon by myself with "toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_good);" ? There's not a default home icon?

Comment: @HugoGresse Ok sorry, I deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a **DrawerToggle** to manage the state of the **DrawerLayout**.

Using a custom icon is really not a good way to achieve this, you should use Material Colors to change the color of the toggle button.

This is a working example of this :

```
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,  R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };


        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Wow, It works Hugo! I really thank you, it's perfect! :)

Comment: I think I chose this as the answer, could you confirm?

Comment: @ManelMendez If the problem has been solved using my answer, yes you should. Don't forget to upvote. If you judge that the question or answer is relevant or usefull, upvote ;)

Comment: I can't upvote yet because I don't have enough reputation, but when I'll have the reputation I'm going to upvote the answer ;) thanks!