# Navigation Drawer icon on the top right is showing Back arrow icon insted of Hamburger icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have Create a new android app with the Navigation Drawer Activity.
When i execute the app, the icon on the right corner is showing the back Arrow but it has to be the 3 line's icon.

The icon R.drawable.ic_drawer is this

[image]

In NavigationDrawerFragment class.

```
// ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
```

When i execute the App i'm getting Arrow icon on the right.

[image]

After the selection also the Icon is same.

[image]

how do i change it now ?

Comment: when you select any of the item from list it will change back to hamburger.

Comment: Is it `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` or `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`? The first one got deprecated. Otherwise it seems normal behavior to me since it will get back to its original shape when closed.

Comment: That is a proper state, the drawer is open. Close it (By selecting an item) and see if it changes to Hamburger. Also I think it is `Top Left` instead of `Top Right`

Comment: it's android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

After selecting also it will be the same Arrow icon.

Comment: Updated my question with the image after selection.

Comment: have you used this line setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) in your actionbar, if yes remove it.

Comment: okay i will give a try.

Comment: Have you checked, is ic drawer image is 3 line image or back arrow image

Comment: check my answer here too http://stackoverflow.com/a/30048816/1377145

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484147/hamburger-icon-does-not-show-in-navigation-drawer-fragment). This work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, I solved the above problem this way. @shkschneider is right. To make your code work import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm little late but this might help other people also.

You just need to add the below line and it will work fine. :)

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```