# Hamburger Icon does not show in Navigation Drawer Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using a Fragement for navigation drawer and hence can't use `onPostCreated` to call syncState

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment{
....
```

Calling `syncState()` on `activityCreated`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Using the `ic_drawer` for icon

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }


    };
```

Can't figure out what is wrong. 
Please help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this problem as well. For me, importing `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` instead of `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` fixed it. You also have to remove the `R.drawable.ic_drawer` argument when you define mDrawerToggle:

`mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
      getActivity(),
      mDrawerLayout,
      R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
      R.string.navigation_drawer_close
)`

If that doesn't work, try some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754940/appcompatv7-v21-navigation-drawer-not-showing-hamburger-icon).

Comment: I'm using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle but no luck any idea?

Comment: @Suchith I was having the save problem, I was overriding the wrong public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState), it must be protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: This does not work me although my code and logic is very similar to the question. but I have this line difference: 
`mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_item_close)`

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer was not solving it for me, I found out I had the wrong override for onPostCreate

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

It must be

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```