# drawerToggle.syncState() isn't syncing icons if put under onPostCreate() but it is if under onCreate()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-drawer

I'm following a tutorial where a guy calls `xxxx.syncState()` from within the `onPostCreate()` method. His app works just fine -- it starts with hamburger icon, which turns into arrow icon. On my side, the icon is arrow all the time but the drawer works.

If I move this `xxxx.syncState()` call above, to the `onCreate()` method (just before its end) -- the behaviour is as expected.

Can anyone tell why is this happening, because I suspect the correct way of doing this is to have it under `onPostCreate()` method? Is android full of things that often need to be done (slightly) differently, creating confusion among novice developers, or there are good reasons due to different versions, etc.?

**[SOLVED]**
This solved my problem: [Arrow is showed instead of the material design version hamburger icon. Why doesn't syncState in onPostCreate work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787036/arrow-is-showed-instead-of-the-material-design-version-hamburger-icon-why-doesn)